# For-Loop indexing issue in R

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing

I have 28 groups of 48 rows in an R dataframe. I'm trying to take the standard deviation of each group. I used the following statement in R Studio:

```
stddev <- vector();
for (i in 1:28) { stddev[i] <- sd(in.subj[((i * 48) -47):(i * 48), 5]); }
```

When I check the values of stddev[] afterward, stddev[1] = NA. Likewise, when I check the standard deviations of individual groups, like sd(in.subj[49:96,5]) I get different values than the for loop printed out.

What would be the cause of these issues?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try :

```
tapply(in.subj[,5], gl(28,48), sd)
```

if there is some NAs in your data :

```
tapply(in.subj[,5], gl(28,48), sd, na.rm=T)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked very well. Can you explain why my statement did not work?